# Degree of Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the book of Harris (Algebraic Geometry), $deg(\mathbb{G}(1,3))$ and $deg(\mathbb{G}(1,4))$ are calculated by specializing of four lines and six planes, respectively. This method can therefore also be used to calculate $deg(\mathbb{G}(1,n))$. Could someone help me to calculate $deg(\mathbb{G}(1,n))$?